# I want to update a custom field (billable) over the JIRA Rest Api but I get an error

Tags: c#, jira

I use the below code in order to **update custom field(check box) "billable"** but it does not update. I get an error.
I also tried to install JIRA REST Browser, but it doesn't update also.

**C# Console Application:**

```
request = new RestRequest("/rest/tempo-timesheets/3/worklogs/{worklogId}", Method.PUT);
request.AddUrlSegment("worklogId", worklogID);
request.AddJsonBody(new
{
       worklogAttributes = new List<object>()
             {
                  new
                      {
                         value = "false",
                         key = "_Nichtabrechenbar_"
                      }
              }
});
```

**Error:**

> {"status-code":500,"stack-trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat
>   com.tempoplugin.worklog.restv3.WorklogsResource$UpdateBeanValidator.getWorklogBuilder(WorklogsResource.java:432)\r\n\tat
>   com.tempoplugin.worklog.restv3.WorklogsResource$BeanValidator.validate(WorklogsResource.java:379)\r\n\tat
>   com.tempoplugin.worklog.restv3.WorklogsResource.updateWorklog(WorklogsResource.java:235)\r\n\tat
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
>
> ....

I hope you can help me!

Comment: This is not JIRA REST API question. What you try to use is Tempo Plugin  REST API.

Comment: Thank you! But it still doesn't work!